# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando consultar un evento de mi BD y este es el código de mi mapper:

```php
public function findById($idEvent){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT e.id_event, e.type, e.name, e.moment, e.date, e.guests, e.children, e.sweet_table, e.observations, e.phone, e.restaurant, e.price FROM event e JOIN user u ON e.restaurant = u.id_user WHERE e.id_event = :i");

        $stmt->bindParam(":i", $idEvent);

        var_dump($stmt->execute());

        $event = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        var_dump($event);

        if($event != null) {
            return new Event(
                $event["id_event"],
                $event["type"],
                $event["name"],
                $event["moment"],
                $event["date"],
                $event["guests"],
                $event["children"],
                $event["sweet_table"],
                $event["observations"],
                $event["restaurant"],
                $event["phone"],
                $event["price"]);
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Y siempre salta el mismo error : _**SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number**__.

$idEvent es un número entero que no llega vacío, y $event si que contiene datos, pero una vez llega al return, siempre salta ese error.

`var_dump($stmt->execute());` siempre devuelve true,
y en `var_dump($event)` muestra correctamente el evento como muestro aqui:

```
  ["id_event"]=>
  int(98)
  ["type"]=>
  string(5) "Otros"
  ["name"]=>
  string(22) "Comida Familiar Prieto"
  ["moment"]=>
  string(7) "Mañana"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "2019-12-21"
  ["guests"]=>
  int(15)
  ["children"]=>
  int(0)
  ["sweet_table"]=>
  int(0)
  ["observations"]=>
  string(15) "sdjfhskjdfhskjh"
  ["phone"]=>
  int(691214567)
  ["restaurant"]=>
  int(51)
  ["price"]=>
  string(5) "62.50"
}
```

Pero luego siempre sale otra vez el error

**{"error":"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"}**

Comment: Me temo que el código que genera esa salida no está localizado en esa función, si no en otra. Fíjate como tú nunca llegas a capturar un posible error SQL, pasaría completamente inadvertido, pero habrá otra zona del código que realiza una consulta SQL o bien donde se captura una excepción con un bloque `try/catch` (incluso podría ser llamando a esta función).

Comment: Busca dónde se genera ese mensaje y agrega a los datos un volcado de llamadas (con [`debug_backtrace()`](https://php.net/debug_backtrace) por ejemplo) o información de depuración adicional como el número de línea real que provoca la excepción con [`Exception::getLine()`](https://php.net/exception.getline) y [`Exception::getFile()`](https://php.net/exception.getfile).

Comment: Gracias Oscar, pero no veo nada extraño con debug_backtrace(), y con los otros métodos no devuelve nada extraño.

Comment: ¿Dónde lo has puesto? ¿En el bloque `catch` o en tu función? Recuerda que debes ponerlo en el bloque `catch` que captura la excepción.

Comment: En el bloque catch no salta la excepción, ni en la propia función, ni capturándolo desde el archivo donde lo llamo.
Sin embargo, si lo llamo solo si muestra un rastro pero nada llamativo :/

Comment: Está claro que ese texto al final de la salida se genera en algún lado, todo apunta a que va acompañado de un `json_encode()`. ¿Qué framework usas? ¿Puedes compartir el código del controlador o la función que llama a esta función?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema es que no haces el bind.

Al parametro '?' tienes que decirle que valor tiene.

por ejemplo: `$sentencia->bind_param("i", $id);`

Aqui encontras informacion muy intersante y en español.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

---

**Edicion por tu comentario**

- Veo que en tu codigo pones: `$stmt->execute(array($idEvent));` cuando deberia ser: `$stmt->execute();`
- Veo que usas `$this->db->` imagino que es una conexión correcta, algo como: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "world");`
- Y por ultimo tu select, la veo muy rara:

`SELECT event.id_event, event.type, event.name, event.moment, event.date, event.guests, event.children, event.sweet_table, event.observations, event.phone, event.restaurant, event.price FROM event, user WHERE event.id_event = ? AND event.restaurant = user.id_user`

Cámbiala así, si te parece bien:

```
 SELECT e.id_event, e.type, e.name, e.moment, e.date, e.guests, e.children,
 e.sweet_table, e.observations, e.phone, e.restaurant, e.price FROM event e JOIN 
 user u ON e.restaurant = u.id_user WHERE e.id_event = ?
```

Esto solo funcionara, si `e.restaurant` tiene esta como *FORANEA* en `u.id_user`

---

**EDICION II**

Se que no es la forma, pero asi descartamos que la query este mal. Prueba esto y dinos que te devuelve.

```
$consulta = "SELECT e.id_event, e.type, e.name, e.moment, e.date, e.guests, e.children,e.sweet_table, e.observations, e.phone, e.restaurant, e.price FROM event e JOIN user u ON e.restaurant = u.id_user WHERE e.id_event = XXX"; //<--AQUI PON UNA ID REAL
$temp = [];
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "bd");
$link->set_charset("utf8") or die();
$resultDir = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);
while ($pos = mysqli_fetch_row($resultDir)) {
  array_push($temp, $pos);
}
var_dump($consulta);
var_dump($link);
var_dump($temp);
```

Así podremos saber si es la conexión, la query o que cosa.
Gracias!

Espero te sirva de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Efectivamente no salta el error, pero sigue sin funcionar.
Muchisimas gracias aun asi ^^

Comment: De nuevo, si no sale, dilo, que lo miramos!

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta para que veas que cambié lo que me sugeriste, pero siempre acaba saltando lo mismo. Probé a pasarle directamente el id del evento y devuelve el mismo error también, ya no se que probar.
Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

@Srsole he probado lo que me has indicado y este ha sido el resultado:

```
string(210) "SELECT e.id_event, e.type, e.name, e.moment, e.date, e.guests, e.children,e.sweet_table, e.observations, e.phone, e.restaurant, e.price FROM event e JOIN user u ON e.restaurant = u.id_user WHERE e.id_event = 98"
object(mysqli)#21 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50012)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(12)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(6) "5.7.23"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50723)
  ["stat"]=>
  string(137) "Uptime: 66840  Threads: 2  Questions: 3765  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 246  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 239  Queries per second avg: 0.056"
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(595)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "98"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Otros"
    [2]=>
    string(22) "Comida Familiar Prieto"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Mañana"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "2019-12-21"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "15"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [8]=>
    string(15) "sdjfhskjdfhskjh"
    [9]=>
    string(9) "691000000"
    [10]=>
    string(2) "51"
    [11]=>
    string(5) "62.50"
  }
}
{"error":"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"}
```

A todo esto, en mi proyecto estoy utilizando PDO, por si acaso influye.

Un saludo!

Comment: Ahora si que me quedo en blanco, todo parece estar correcto... las tablas event y user estan con clave foranea?

Comment: Así llevo yo desde que me apareció el error. Si, está bien, de hecho repasé el script de la BD y la tabla Event termina tal que así:
 PRIMARY KEY (id_event),
 FOREIGN KEY (restaurant) REFERENCES user(id_user) ON DELETE CASCADE
Borraré la BD y la volveré a crear por si acaso?

Comment: Hombre si vas a hacerlo, pon los scripts en la pregunta, y me lo pruebo yo en local y te digo algo, y ya que estamos ponme el trocito donde creas la conexion a la BD (en tu caso $this->db). Lo pruebo y a ver si a mi tambien me peta

Comment: y algunos datos para poblar las tablas tambien porfa

Comment: @Srsole Nada, no funciona borrando la BD tampoco. Creo que pasaré la duda a los profesores y cuando me den solución (si la dan) la pondré por aquí.
Porque el resto de consultas (por ejemplo las comidas) están hechas igualmente, con la misma conexión y si que funciona.

Mil gracias por todas las ideas y la ayuda ^^

Comment: De nada se hace lo que se puede. Suerte